# Is it dangerous to go extreme pig riding in a thunderstorm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I like to saddle up my piggy for a ride into thunderstorms. But what happens to my piggy if we get hit by lightning?

Comment: One day, he will grow wings, and we'll fly above and beyond all the troubles of the world ~

Comment: @Sadly Not [You were right!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKMYXBY5oQU)

Answer (score 190, accepted):

If a pig, saddled and ridden or not, gets hit by lightning it will turn into an un-aggro'ed (non-hostile) Zombie Pigman with you staring at the inside of it's head.

Lightning forced to strike with a mod.

[image: pig]
[image: saddled]
[image: inside of pigzombie head]
[image: pigzombie]

Comment: +1 In-game testing with pictures is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: hostile or not?

Comment: @Ark, non-hostile

Comment: Unless you start hitting it.

Comment: Wanna breed them!

Comment: @Nakilon, Good Luck! As these guys are only found in the Nether

Comment: @GipsyD Unless luck says to smite a pig with lightning.